# A prime ideal of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and let $P$ be prime ideal of $R$ consider the polymial ring $R[x]$ and let $P[x]$ be the ideal of $R[x]$ consisting of polynomials whose coefficient all belongs to $P$ show that the ideal $$P[x]+<x>$$ is prime ideal.

I know that $P[x] $ is also prime ideal. I don't know how to show that $P[x]+<x>$ is prime ideal.

Please give some hint.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you show that $P[X]$ is a prime ideal?

Comment: Duplicate of [3069658](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069658/show-that-px-langle-x-rangle-is-a-prime-ideal-of-rx?rq=1).

Comment: Your ideal is $(P,x)$ then $R[x]/(P,x) = R[x]/(x)/(P) \cong R/(P)$. If $P$ is a prime ideal this is an integral domain so $(P,x)$ is a prime ideal. The other prime ideal is $(P)$ (that you called $P[x]$) as $R[x]/(P) = (R/P)[x]$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*. An ideal $I ⊆ A$ of a ring $A$ is prime if and of $A/I$ is an integral domain. For $A = R[X]$ and $I = P[X] + (X)$ in your case, use that you have an isomorphism
$$R[X]/P[X] \to (R/P)[X],$$
sending the residue class $[X]$ to $X$. (You might already know *both* this trick to show something is a prime ideal *and* this isomorphism from the proof for the fact that $P[X]$ is prime in $R[X]$.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** take an element $q$ of $P[X] + \langle X \rangle$. This means that there exists a polynomial $p$ with coefficients in $P$ and a polynomial $r$ with coefficients in $R$ such that

$$
q = p + Xr.
$$

In particular, all but the $0$-th degree term of $q$ belong to $R$ but not necessarily to $P$. Conversely, suppose that $q = a_nX^n + \dots + a_1X + a_0 \in R[X]$ is such that $a_0 \in P$. Then, we have

$$
q = a_0 + X(a_nX^{n-1} + \dots + a_1) \in P + \langle X \rangle \subset P[X] + \langle X \rangle.
$$

This shows that $P[X] + \langle X \rangle = P \oplus \langle X \rangle$. On the other hand, $R[X]$ can be written as $\langle X \rangle \oplus R$.

Think about what these descriptions tell you about $R[X]/P[X] + \langle X \rangle$.

> Concretely, we have that $R[X]/P[X] + \langle X \rangle = \frac{\langle X \rangle \oplus R}{\langle X \rangle \oplus P} \simeq \frac{\langle X \rangle}{\langle X \rangle} \oplus \frac{R}{P} \simeq 0 \oplus R/P \simeq R/P.$ Since $P$ is prime, the former quotient is a domain, and thus $P[X] + \langle X \rangle$ is prime.